# запуск функции в отдельном потоке openmp

Tags: c, многопоточность, openmp

Пытаюсь задать функцию в отдельном потоке. Но почему-то не выходит вот код :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void send_func(int s_v); //отправка
void reception_func(int s_v); // приём

int main()
{
        omp_set_num_threads(1);
        // фукция отправки
        send_func(10);

         omp_set_num_threads(1);
        // функция приёма
        reception_func(10);

}

// omp_set_num_threads(1); // так вообще выдаёт ошибку 
void send_func(int s_v)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(1);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){printf("Thread %d | 1 s_v = %d \n",omp_get_thread_num(),s_v);}
}

// omp_set_num_threads(1); // так вообще выдаёт ошибку 
void reception_func(int s_v)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(1);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){printf("Thread %d | 2 s_v = %d \n",omp_get_thread_num(), s_v);}
}
```

Увы всё исполняет в одном потоке ;_;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void send_func(int s_v); //отправка
void reception_func(int s_v); // приём

int main()
{

#pragma omp parallel sections
    // тут запукстить два потока  ПО одному !!!
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
//        omp_set_num_threads(1);
        // фукция отправки
        send_func(10);
        }
#pragma omp section
        {
//        omp_set_num_threads(1);
        // функция приёма
        reception_func(10);
        }
    }
}

void send_func(int s_v)
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){printf("Thread %d | 1 s_v = %d \n",omp_get_thread_num(),s_v);}
}

void reception_func(int s_v)
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){printf("Thread %d | 2 s_v = %d \n",omp_get_thread_num(), s_v);}
}
```

Вот вывод программы:

```
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 1 | 1 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10 
Thread 0 | 2 s_v = 10
```

Comment: Все гуд, но omp_set_num_threads точно не нужен), лучше выше максимум потоков обозначить)

Comment: через omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());

Comment: @Andrey исправил, так же почему-то гонит на вызов                                   /home/comp/Qt_project/untopenmp/main.c:25: ошибка: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     int n = omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Эм... написано же воид. Это функция не возвращает значение, что Вы хотите записать в n? Это просто сеттер

Comment: В сети есть манул по omp 40 страниц - за час все поймёте )

Comment: @Andrey , а можно ссылку на "описание библиотеки " , либо название документации (а то в интернете много всего могу и запутаться ). omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());  . omp_get_max_threads()- даёт масимально количество потоков которые возможны в компе. omp_set_num_threads() -  ??

Comment: https://hpc.icc.ru/documentation/msu/OpenMP.pdf